# Updating one table using information from another

Tags: sql-server

[image: Working hour locations]

I have two tables:

- table one consists of work days and hours worked
- table two consists of work locations and starting dates

Using table 2 I am hoping to identify work locations in table 1 (as in desired result column).

Comment: Just to clarify, are those tables on the same database - same server or different servers?

Comment: Have you tried researching this online? Have you searched Stack Overflow for similar questions?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `APPLY` and `TOP`:

```
SELECT
    t1.*, x.WorkPlace
FROM Table1 t1
CROSS APPLY(
    SELECT TOP(1) WorkPlace
    FROM Table2 t2
    WHERE t1.WorkDays >= t2.Date
    ORDER BY t2.Date DESC
) x
```